# Best way to split a dataset every Nth observation

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

Currently, I have 3 datasets each 1368 rows of data points.

```
a <- sample(0:10000,1368, rep=TRUE)
Df <- data.frame(obs=c(1:1368),
                 var1=a)


df2<-data.frame(col1=Df$var1[1:90],
                col2=Df$var1[91:180],
                col3=Df$var1[181:270])
Dataset 1
  col1 col2 col3
1  7878 8130 3924
2  5781 4375 6232
3  9324 9066 1734
4  9754 8796 2047
5  3462 4930 7381
6  7379 8103 3404
7  7355 5212 4505

dataset 2
  col1 col2 col3
1  7878 8130 3924
2  5781 4375 6232
3  9324 9066 1734
4  9754 8796 2047
5  3462 4930 7381
6  7379 8103 3404
7  7355 5212 4505
8  5599 6887 5775
9  2321 7948 3553
10 3717 1248 5818
11 6276 5528  206
12 1328 1158 8681
13 4470 3009 1332
14 6472 9018  606
```

An example of one of the datasets that is being used with the expected outcome, I left out the excess rows.

My intention is to split each dataset sequentially into subsets, each with 90 observations. I am aware of the divisible issue, but the last subset having more entries isn't a problem, the main concern is just splitting the observations into either different datasets or different columns to perform specific statistical tests such as a T-test on each subset of data. The end result should a data frame with 14 columns.

The end goal is to have all 3 datasets of 1368 observations split into equal subsets.

What would be the best way to split the dataset into these subsets?

Comment: Your data set is not so large that you need to split it.Interpreting the multiple test results for each replicate test will take you longer than just running the tests on the entire datasets.

Comment: We'd be better able to help if you would provide an example of data and expected result.

Comment: I apologise for not adding an example of data and expected result, I updated it now

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started, but without reproducible data, it is impossible to adapt a general method to your specific data:

```
n <- 1368    # rows
subsets <- n %/% 90   # 15 subsets
extra <- n %% 90      # 18 extra
grp <- c(rep(1:subsets, each=90), rep(subsets, extra))  # group numbers for each row assuming the extra goes in the last group
table(grp)
# grp
#   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15 
#  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90 108
```

Then use `grp` to `split()` your data frame into a list of groups.